# PHP header location not working with clean urls

Tags: php, http-headers

```
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (!$result) {
        $url.="/signup";
        header("Location:".$url);
    } else {
        $url.="/home";
        header("Location:".$url);
    }
    ?>
```

Hello friends I am in a bit problem I am doing a project and using clean urls my htaccess is good everything is going good but after a signup form submission when I want to change header location
php gives an error can't change header location
kindly help

[image: PHP Error]

Comment: Are you sure you're sending headers before any other HTML output?

Comment: no I am not sending header 
html form and php code both are in same file 
the form action is (action="")

Comment: Your error is on line 147, that means you probably have plenty of HTML before the call to `header()`.

Comment: yeah there is plenty of html before this and White space doing everything wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would post a comment but I dont have enought rep.

Anyway, probably you are seeing error about headers already sent. It is common problem and it have nothing to do with clean urls. what you can do?

## 1. Make sure you are not outputting anything before header() call

Problem is based on fact how web server and HTTP works. When you are outputting server will send headers and content as soon as it is ready. And you may be outputting even whitespaces, so double check this first.

## 2. Turn on output buffering

If for any reason you need to output something before headers manipulation, you can turn on output buffering. This way server first "buffers" your data and then sents everything out. Hovewer you are paying in load time for this. Use only rarely, when it is really needed!

You can use [a ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)for this

Answer (score 1):

If that is your PHP script, I can see whitespaces before `<?php` tag.

```
    <?php
^^^^--- WHITESPACES
```

These whitespaces will be written to output buffer even before PHP interpreter kicks in, and when you call `header()` it will give an error. This is because no output should be sent to client before calling `header()`.